# ASP.NET Core 6 request has a value but when running LINQ query the application crashes

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Handler

```
    public GetDataManagementHandler(IRepository<CaseEntity> repository, IRepository<EmployeeEntity> repoEmployee, IMapper mapper, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _repoEmployee = repoEmployee;
    }
```

Offending code within Handler

```
var data = await _repository.Table.ToListAsync();
data = data.Where(it => it.CoordinatorName.Contains(request.caseDtos.CoordinatorName)).ToList();
```

CaseEntity

```
public class CaseEntity : BaseEntity,  ISoftDeletedEntity
{
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public string CaseID { get; set; }
    public long? EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeFullName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeFirstName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeLastName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayCaseCode { get; set; }
    public string CaseStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RequestDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FrequencyEffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public string ReasonName { get; set; }
    public string FrequencyType { get; set; }
    public string ApprovalStatus { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string? CoordinatorName { get; set; }
    public Decimal? FMLAHoursTaken { get; set; }
    public Decimal? FLAHoursTaken { get; set; }
    public long? InternalCaseID { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

The crash

```
{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<FMLA.Core.Tables.CaseEntity>}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2147467261
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    Source: "System.Linq"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1[[FMLA.Core.Tables.CaseEntity, FMLA.Core, Version=2023.2.22.4771, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].ToArray()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[CaseEntity](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1[[FMLA.Core.Tables.CaseEntity, FMLA.Core, Version=2023.2.22.4771, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].get_Items()"
    TargetSite: {FMLA.Core.Tables.CaseEntity[] ToArray()}
```

request.caseDtos

[image: value of request.caseDtos]

CaseFilterDto definition

```
public class CaseFilterDto : PageInput
{
    public string CaseId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string? CoordinatorName { get; set; }
    public bool IsDistinct { get; set; }
}
```

These LINQ statements work

```
            var coordinatorName = data.Select(it => it.CoordinatorName).ToList();
            var results = coordinatorName.Where(it => it.Contains(request.caseDtos.CoordinatorName));
            data = data.Where(it => it.CoordinatorName.ToLower().Contains(request.caseDtos.CoordinatorName.ToLower())).ToList(); // CRASH HERE
```

Comment: @Dai its not null

Comment: In one of the records CoordinatorName is null.

Comment: @ScottHannen you are correct. Some values maybe null. What can I do to ignore those records that are null?

Comment: @ScottHannen I made all the null values into '' (empty string) and it still crashed with the same result/stacktrace

Comment: Here's another approach. Press CTRL-ALT-E to open exception settings. Check the box for common language runtime exceptions. That ensures that when the exception is thrown the code will immediately break into the debugger. (Maybe it's already doing that.) When that happens you can move your mouse over the different variables and find out what is null. Something has to be. We made assumptions/guesses but it could be something else. But if you do that it will likely take away the guessing and show you the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

In one of the entries, `CoordinatorName` is null. Change it to `CoordinatorName?`

Since you are calling `.ToListAsync()`, entire recordset is now in memory, C# will throw null reference exception as it has no idea of what you want to do.

Ideally you should not use `ToListAsync()`, and everything will work correctly.

Comment: The table may contain null values for Coordinator names. Shouldn't the query just skip those records that are null?

Comment: You're calling ToListAsync on the records. So when you get to the Linq query it's not executing against the database. It's operating on an in-memory collection of objects.

Comment: @ScottHannen but shouldnt the value come from the database when it's performing an in memory comparison operation?

Comment: Everything comes from the database. But that's done. Now you have a list of objecta. It doesn't matter any more where they came from. If CoordinatorName is null and you call CoordinatorName.Contains you'll get that error. It doesn't matter if it's in a Linq query or if you just did it with a single instance. Linq is just checking CoordinatorName.Contains on each object, and if one of them is null it throws an exception. Akash's answer will work because it handles the case where CoordinatorName is null.